# What is the difference between these update CALLBACK functions code?

Tags: node.js, json, curl

I had ran the codes shown below. The 1st one runs but 2nd one does not
    Can anyone please tell me the reason behind it.

```
   //This runned successfully

    updatePost(req,res)
    { 
         let postId = req.params.postId
        let posts = req.store.posts
        posts[postId] = req.body
        res.status(200).send(posts[postId])
    }

    //This gave error

     updatePost(req,res)
    { 
         req.store.posts[req.params.postId]=req.body
         res.send(200).send(req.store.posts[req.params.postId])
    }
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error message....your last line is res.send(200).send(req.store.posts[req.params.postId]),

When it gets to ".send(req.store.posts[req.params.postId])" the response has already been sent.

Try changing it to `res.status(200).send(req.store.posts[req.params.postId])`
Like you have in the first block of code.

If this isn't your problem (maybe thats just a typo in your question and not in your code), please share the error message and I'll update my answer.